# Having an issue with a return statement

Tags: swift

With the code below I keep getting this error under return and cannot seem to find a solution.

> Cannot convert value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' to expected argument type '[UINib.OptionsKey : Any]?'

```
//
//  Created by Stevoo 10/17/2022
//  From: https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift.Library
//  License: MIT License
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

public extension NibResourceType {
  /**
   Instantiate the nib to get the top-level objects from this nib

   - parameter ownerOrNil: The owner, if the owner parameter is nil, connections to File's Owner are not permitted.
   - parameter options: Options are identical to the options specified with -[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]

   - returns: An array containing the top-level objects from the NIB
   */
  public func instantiate(withOwner ownerOrNil: Any?, options optionsOrNil: [AnyHashable : Any]? = [:]) -> [Any] {
    return UINib(resource: self).instantiate(withOwner: ownerOrNil, options: optionsOrNil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `UINib.instantiate(withOwner:options:)`. The options parameter needs to be of type `[UINib.OptionsKey : Any]`.

You could change your function's `optionsOrNil` parameter to be of type `[UINib.OptionsKey : Any]?` instead of `[AnyHashable : Any]?` or you could try to cast it to that type with `as?`:

```
  public func instantiate(withOwner ownerOrNil: Any?, options optionsOrNil: [UINib.OptionsKey : Any]? = [:]) -> [Any] {
    return UINib(resource: self).instantiate(withOwner: ownerOrNil, options: optionsOrNil)
  }
```

or

```
  public func instantiate(withOwner ownerOrNil: Any?, options optionsOrNil: [AnyHashable : Any]? = [:]) -> [Any] {
    let castOptions = optionsOrNil as? [UINib.OptionsKey : Any]
    return UINib(resource: self).instantiate(withOwner: ownerOrNil, options: castOptions)
  }
```

Changing your function to take the correct type seems like the better solution.